# Trait 'SamuelNitsche\AuthLog\AuthLogable' not found on Laravel

Tags: github, composer-php, laravel-8, traits, putty

Recently connected a Laravel project with Github by Tortoise & Putty. Thinking to install a fresh new composer in this project. But problem is, when I Tried to install/update/dump-autoload composer; it's showing this error below -

```
Install of samuelnitsche/laravel-auth-log failed
3/3 [============================] 100%
                                                                                
[RuntimeException]                                                            
Failed to execute git clone --no-checkout -- https://ghp...0Gu:x-oauthbasic@github.com/SamuelNitsche/laravel-auth-log.git G:\xampp\htdocs\ex.institute\vendor\samuelnitsche\laravel-auth-log && cd /D G:\xampp\htdocs\ex.institute\vendor\samuelnitsche\laravel-auth-log && git remote add composer -- https://ghp...0Gu:x-oauth-basic@github.com/SamuelNitsche/laravel-auth-log.git && git fetch composer && git remote set-url origin -- https://github.com/SamuelNitsche/laravel-auth-log.git && git remote set-url composer -- https://github.com/SamuelNitsche/laravel-auth-log.git                                                                        
                                                                                
Cloning into 'G:\xampp\htdocs\ex.institute\vendor\samuelnitsche\laravel-auth-log'...remote: Repository not found.                                                 
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/SamuelNitsche/laravel-auth-log.git/' not found
```

Comment: The repository of that package is gone. See as well https://packagist.org/packages/samuelnitsche/laravel-auth-log : _"This package is **abandoned** and no longer maintained. The author suggests using [...]"_

Comment: You are right. I had found the main problem. I connected this project with putty. & Recently I moved my putty private key into another folder. So, it's not linked rightly. Now I linked private putty key with this project, it's works fine.